# How to create a numpy array filled with average value of a vector

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, math, data-visualization

I am not sure how to phrase my question in any way better. Basically, I have three lists of the same length `x`, `y` and `z` and I want to fill a 2D numpy array in the z/y plane with the average of the associated z values.

Here is how I can achieve what I wan to do:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [37.59390426045407, 38.00530354847739, 38.28412244348653, 38.74871247986305, 38.73175910429809, 38.869008864244016, 39.188234404976555, 39.92835838352555, 40.881394113153334, 41.686136269465884]
y = [0.1305391767832006, 0.13764519613447768, 0.14573326951792354, 0.15090729309032114, 0.16355823707239897, 0.17327106424274763, 0.17749746339532224, 0.17310384614773594, 0.16545780437882962, 0.1604752704890856]
z = [0.05738534353865021, 0.012572155256903583, -0.021709582561809437, -0.11191337750722108, -0.07931921785775153, -0.06241610118871843, 0.014216349927058225, 0.042002641153291886, -0.029354425271534645, 0.061894011359833856]

n = 5
image = np.zeros(shape=(n,n))

# Fill the 2D array
x0 = min(x)
y0 = min(y)
dx = (max(x) - min(x))/n
dy = (max(y) - min(y))/n
# Loop over each 2D cell
for index_x in range(n):
    for index_y in range(n):
        # find the limits of the cell 
        x1 = x0 + index_x * dx
        x2 = x0 + (index_x+1) * dx
        y1 = y0 + index_y * dy
        y2 = y0 + (index_y+1) * dy
        # find the points of z that lie within the range of the cell
        vec_z = [z[idx] for idx in range(len(z)) if x[idx]>=x1 and x[idx]<x2 and y[idx]>=y1 and y[idx]<y2]
        if vec_z:
            image[index_x, index_y] = np.mean(vec_z)

# In the end, used to create a surface plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(image, cmap=plt.cm.gray, interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

Is there a more easy way to achieve this? I can imagine there is a `numpy` method for that.

Comment: actually you just want to bin the data and fill the bins with the average, but you do not care where these bins are? e.g. in your example you use `n=5` and that splits evenly across minimum and maximum values ...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you want to do, maybe a 2D interpolation from [`scipy.interpolate.interp2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html) is what you are looking for.
You define the interpolation function of your points:

```
f = interp2d(x = x, y = y, z = z)
```

Then you define the `X` and `Y` meshgrid:

```
N = 50
x_axis = np.linspace(np.min(x), np.max(x), N)
y_axis = np.linspace(np.min(y), np.max(y), N)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x_axis, y_axis)
```

Finally you can compute `Z` interpolated values on the meshgrid:

```
Z = np.zeros((N, N))
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        Z[i, j] = f(X[i, j], Y[i, j])
```

---

If you plot in 3D the interpolated surface, you get:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection = '3d')

ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap = 'jet', shade = False)

ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Interpolated surface compared to interpolation data points:

```
ax.scatter(x, y, z, color = 'black', s = 100, alpha = 1)
```

[image]